# Angular2: How to run jQuery initialization scripts on route change?

Tags: jquery, angular, angular2-routing

I have an element in an Angular2 app that loads fine when I refresh the page or go to it initially, but is hidden when I change the route to the parent page. I am using some purchased styles/js and when I searched the element name I found some functions inside of a .ready() call that show the element and adjust its height. I believe the issue is that these init scripts run the first time, but then when I change routes they do not execute. I need these scripts throughout the website and I can't really split them up because they're minified. I tried just popping all the scripts into the bottom of the component's HTML but this did not work (not that I expected it to).

If this isn't enough info I can pastebin the js and the element in question but this seems to me like something that would come up a lot and therefore have an easy, generic fix.

Comment: So far my best (horrible) solution is: `this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
      if (evt instanceof ResolveStart && this.router.url !== '/home' && evt.url == '/home' && this.router.url !== '/' && this.router.url !== evt.url){
        window.location.href = window.location.origin;
      }})`

Comment: I have added one more solution, you can try that.

Comment: @SneakyBeaver his solution will work for you. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me with a theme that wasn't Angular ready as well, I'm pretty sure that there should be a cleaner way to solve it at this time, but it worked for me at that moment. Load your theme's js library into your main component:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (document.getElementById("yourLibUniqueId")) {
        document.getElementById("yourLibUniqueId").remove();
    }

    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "lib/yourLib.js";
    s.id = "yourLibUniqueId";
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `activate` method of `router-outlet` as:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

Then in `onActivate` do whatever you want.